# Determine if user skips login in FBSession (openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to clear token information etc if user tapped skip during login with facebook. The login itself is:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_events", @"friends_events"] 
                                   allowLoginUI:YES 
                              completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     if (!error)
          // do something depending on state
     }
 }];
```

The problem is i can't find out if user 'skipped' the login. The approach with `publish_stream` on `permissions` doesn't have sense here because i nether request nor need `publish_stream`.

The console output is following:

```
session: <FBSession: ___, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: ___, appID: ___, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: ___>, expirationDate: _IN_THE_FUTURE_, refreshDate: _CURRENT_TIME_, attemptedRefreshDate: ___, permissions:(
    email,
    "user_events",
    "friends_events"
)>
error: <nil>
(FBSessionState) state = FBSessionStateOpen
```

So everything looks fine even though i pressed 'Skip'. Is there any way to determine if skip was pressed..?

Comment: If the user tapped skip, then there's no token information to begin with, so why do you need to clear it?

Comment: @MingLi Well truth. However still i need to determine if he logged in because later i have to show alert before logging out etc.

Comment: If the user skipped login, then the active session will NOT be in an open state, so you should be able to check [[FBSession activeSession] isOpen], and only log out if true.

Comment: @MingLi That's not true - as you can see, the state i'm receiving from FB is open - all the infos are passed and the session is opened.

Comment: Has the user authorized your app previously somehow? If they've never authorized your app before, AND they pressed skip, then you should not have an access token, and the session should NOT be in an opened state. Also, is this for iOS integrated login, SSO login, or webview login?

Comment: Yes, they could have authorized app before, log out and log in again with pressing skip this time then the session IS in opened state. For the second part of question: it is not SSO (as you may understand from previous sentence), iOS integrated.

Comment: So this really just means that they skipped giving you additional permissions? Because if your session is open, then you have a valid access token, and you should show the logout scenario anyways.

Comment: @MingLi No, the session is not open. It is closed when user logged out of the app. He can log in again - permissions are the same. Permissions do not change on Facebook. So when user wants to login with Facebook and cancels he should NOT be logged in with Facebook even though the permission were given once long time ago (but they do not change nor expire). My session is open and i get valid token even tho i shouldn't because user skipped the login this time. This is a bug in FB API.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the "skip" step? I only see OK and Don't Allow as the options for iOS integrated login.